# How to disable LXDE and use Openbox

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, 14.10, openbox

i'm using Lubuntu 14.10 for old laptop and i would like to disable LXDE and use just Openbox window manager as default envroment at logon.

Do you know how to do it?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just choose it at log in.  It should be one of your choices along with Lubuntu and Lubuntu netbook.  Once you choose it and log in, it will become the default until you choose something else.  Be prepared for a bare bones system.

Comment: Oh thanks, i was using autologin, so haven't seen it until manual logout.